# Used \newgeometry and got big chunk of empty space at the bottom of the page

Tags: geometry

I used \newgeometry in landscape environment, followed by the table that you can see in the image and  I added \restoregeometry before ending landscape.

How to use \newgeometry properly, that this empty space (1/3 of the page?) won't appear?

[image]

Comment: Using `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` necessarily inserts a page break to accommodate for the possible change in page layout/size. You may have to place these *outside* your `landscape` environment.

Comment: @Werner now when I placed it outside landscape the top 1/3 of the page is empty :d

Comment: In order to better address the problems you may experience, consider posting code that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile that replicates your display. The code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Until then, it's really a guessing game of what the issue might be. You can edit your post (ideally), or post content to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com).